# How to use local tiles for map

Tags: html, leaflet, gis, openstreetmap, mapbox

I am using mapbox with openstreet map to create my map. but i want to put the tiles locally. thus reducing traffic and the time taken to load the map.
i am using [Mobile atlas creator MOBAC](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/) to get the tiles in jpg format, this is the HTML i am usually using

```js
var cities = new L.LayerGroup(); var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenstreetMap</a> contributors, ' + '
<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' + 'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>', mbUrl = 'https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'; var grayscale = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}',
{id: 'remote-sensing.n8k508ak', attribution: mbAttr, accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmVtb3RlLXNlbnNpbmciLCJhIjoiYWNiYzg0ZWU2Mjk3ZTU5NjE4MmQyZWEzZTY2ZWNlYjIifQ.U7mp4MXdcjaIwW_syAqriQ'}) , streets = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}',
{id: 'remote-sensing.84f6c85a', attribution: mbAttr, accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmVtb3RlLXNlbnNpbmciLCJhIjoiYWNiYzg0ZWU2Mjk3ZTU5NjE4MmQyZWEzZTY2ZWNlYjIifQ.U7mp4MXdcjaIwW_syAqriQ'});
```

Any idea on how to do this. thanks in advance

Comment: Did you already try to point `mbUrl` to a local directory containing your map tiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need is a common use case, and it is easily do-able once you have the tiles somewhere in your file system, provided that they are still available as tiles with coordinates as part of their file name or access path.

Using MOBAC is a technique called "tiles scrapping": *make sure it is compatible with the terms of use of your tile source!*

The easiest solution is to scrap your tiles in a format that preserves the path structure. For example the "OSMTracker tile storage". It will create one folder per zoom level, then one folder per X value, then one tile per Y value.

Then simply replace your URL (first argument of `L.tileLayer`) by your folder structure. Assuming you have saved your local tiles in the same folder as your HTML page, the URL would be something like `"{z}/{x}/{y}.png"`. No longer need for access token.

Comment: i did have them as  "OSMTracker tile storage" but it still had them in files with normal numbers and not x and y values, is there anything i am missig? @Ghybs

Comment: , and for best result , any idea what map source should i use?? the default was OpenStreetMap MapQuest,thank you

Comment: As for the map source, it is a matter of personal preference. You could browse http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/ to make up your choice, but make sure the one you choose allows you to do tile scraping. The OSM MapQuest is very lax about usage, so you could keep it. It is unclear for how long MapQuest will keep that service open, so you'd better scrap soon. As for your tile names, what do you mean by normal numbers instead of x and y values?

Comment: thanks, never mind about the x y thing it was my mistake, i will try adding to tha map, thanks for the help.